# how to find the files less than 5 MB in /var/log/ and display with the size of file?

Tags: command-line, disk-usage

I need to find the files less than 5 MB in /var/log/ and the output should display the size of each files. which command should I use?

Answer (score 2):

This command will find the files in `/var/log` that are less than 5M in size *and* print the size (in kilobytes) along with the file name:

```
find /var/log -maxdepth 1 -size -5M -type f -printf '%5k %f\n'
```

Sample output might look like:

```
  112 syslog.6.gz
 1048 messages.1
  112 syslog.5.gz
  120 syslog.7.gz
 1216 syslog.1
```

#### How it works

- `-maxdepth 1` tells find not to descend into subdirectories.  (If you want subdirectories to be included, omit this)
- `-size -5M` tells find to limit the results to file less than 5M in size.
- `-type f` tells find to look only for regular files.
- `-printf '%5k %f\n'` tells find to allocate 5 spaces to the size and print the size in kilobytes, followed by a space, followed by the file's name.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
find /var/log/ -name * -size -5M -ls | awk '{ print $11 " has a size of " $7 }'
```

Update June 01:
In a newer Ubuntu Server version the `-name *` isn't available but you can now use this:

```
find /var/log/ -type f -size -5M -ls | awk '{ print $11 " has a size of " $7 }'
```

If you need a more human readable version this one would be a nice option

```
find /var/log/ -type f -size -5M -exec ls -lsh {} \; | awk '{ print $10 " has a size of " $1 }'
```